# Need to create a ubuntu bionic image 64 server using vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, server, windows-10, vagrant

Windows10 host

command for initalize vagrant file

```
vagrant init ubuntu/bionic64
```

The error message got:

> Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage: The executable
> 'cmd.exe' Vagrant is trying to run was not found in the %PATH%
> variable. This is an error. Please verify this software is installed
> and on the path.

Need help for resolving this

Answer (score 0):

Firstly in Environment Variable where Set the Path Variable to `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`
Apply & Ok the settings
Rerun the git bash(iam using gitbash terminal, as per your terminal rerun it).
It will definitely work.
for more understanding refer from here : [This will help](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/issues/363)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).